# Ubuntu laptop connected to usb modem and set to be a hotspot + nexus 7

Tags: wireless, 12.10, laptop, hot-spot, nexus-7

I'm using my laptop as a wifi hotspot while it's connected to broadband over a usb stick.
And it works perfectly, I connect my phone to the laptop hotspot without a problem.
But my nexus 7 can't find the hotspot, it's just not detecting it.

What settings should I change so it could work? I've been searching for days but I can't find the solution...

Comment: the only thing I have found googling was this app:
http://tinyurl.com/9r2sk8f
and maybe go to advanced settings and disable hide poor connections.
3 people confirmed working, if not, I have no solutions.

Comment: Can we assume you are still running the **Nexus 7** with Android **4.x** ?  (and not Ubuntu on Android)

Answer (score 0):

Install dnsmasq-base first

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq-base
```

Click on the `Network Manager` icon at TOP right panel and select the `Create New Wireless` 
give your connection a name (you can even add encryption if you want.) Click on `Create`
Choose security option as per your requirement. Now when you search for a WiFi connection on your WiFi device you would see the one  you just created connect to it.